any technical term to describe the red portion along the slot?
what is the technical term to describe the red line, any difference between A and B picture if we specify clearly? below are some that I can think of
•   unslotted portion ( For both A and B )
•   unslotted portion along the slot ( For both A and B )
•   portion along the slot ( Both for A and B)
•   portion opposite to the slot ( Only for A )
•   portion opposite to the slot opening ( only for A )
any correction or more precise term you could teach me are highly appreciated.


It would be nice if you can number them and label them on the pictures.

A is a cross lap joint ... B is a mortise and tenon joint ... try asking at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions

the term is probably something like remaining material
